# CMake Visual Studio: glew32d.dll not found on running

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2017, glew

I'm having trouble running my project with Visual Studio 2017.

Visual Studio complains about not beeing able to find the glew32d.dll whenever I want to execute my program (debug mode).

#### Note:

My goal is to let CMake compile glew and GLFW from source and then link it against my own project which also has to be compiled.

## Folder Structure

```
root_project
  |─── CMakeLists.txt
  |─── Project 1
  |      |─── .h and .cpp files
  |      └─── CMakeLists.txt
  |─── Dependency 1 (glfw)
  |      |─── include directory
  |      |─── source directory
  |      |─── ...
  |      └─── CMakeLists.txt
  └─── Dependency 2 (glew)
         |─── build
         |      └─── cmake
         |            └─── CMakeLists.txt
         |─── source directory
         |─── include directory
         └─── ...
```

## CMake files

My root cmake file:

```
project ("EbsiStaller") # root_project

add_subdirectory ("EbsiStaller") # Project 1

set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

# Adds the CMakeLists.txt file located in the specified directory
# as a build dependency.
add_subdirectory ("glfw")
include_directories("glfw/include")

target_link_libraries(glfw INTERFACE
   ${GLFW_LIBRARIES}
)

add_subdirectory ("glew/build/cmake")
target_include_directories(glew PUBLIC 
    "glew/include"
)
target_link_libraries(glew INTERFACE
    ${GLEW_LIBRARIES}
)
```

My project cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

add_executable (EbsiStaller 
    "....cpp" 
    "....h"
)

target_compile_features(EbsiStaller PUBLIC
    cxx_std_17
)

# Links the CMake build output against glfw.
target_link_libraries(EbsiStaller 
    glfw 
    glew
)
```

## Additional Notes:

I don't have much experience with CMake and I'm using the CMake version Visual Studio comes with.

## My assumption:

My own assumption would be that probably something with my CMake files is incorrect which causes this problem. This means I would like to know how I can fix this specific problem but I'm also wondering how I can change it to create a static file and not the dynamic dll file.

Comment: I don't see any code copying `glew32d.dll` into location where your executable will be able to find it.

Comment: There is no such code as I didn't know that such code is required. **1.** How would such code look like? **2.** How could I change it to compile the static lib and not the dll?

Comment: 1. Typically this is performed as a post build step. However I have no idea how to make cmake emit proper project with post build step actions. 2. something like `add_library(glew STATIC` when building glew.

Comment: contrary to linux where you can play with LD_LIBRARY_PATH to help dynamic load, on windows the best approach is to put lib and bin in the same output dir dirty: set CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY and CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY to the same dir on windows to run from your build dir e.g. ${CMAKE_BUILD_DIR}/bin in the CMakeLists.txt root, you could also build as static all dependencies it will avoid to try to find them ^^ then you have to do the same for the build rules...